# Is it possible to calculate yearly beta, alpha and rsquared with a dataframe of multiple years?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yfinance

I am working on the following project and I am having issues with calculating the yearly beta, alpha and rsquared instead of a single one of each one for the whole 6 years of data I have.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import datetime
import yfinance as yf
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels import regression

yf.pdr_override()

cryptos = ["BTC", "ETH", "XRP", "BCH", "USDT", #"BSV",  #BSV does not have data in yahoo finance for the time period requested
"LTC", "BNB", "EOS", "LINK", "XMR",
"BTG", "ADA", "XLM", "TRX", "USDC"]

def get_and_process_data(c):
    raw_data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(c + '-USD', start="2015-01-01", end="2021-01-01")
    return raw_data.Close.pct_change()[1:]

df = pd.DataFrame({c: get_and_process_data(c) for c in cryptos})

df['MKT Return'] = df.mean(axis=1) # avg market return
print(df) # show dataframe with all data

def model(x, y):
    # Calculate r-squared
    X = sm.add_constant(x) # artificially add intercept to x, as advised in the docs
    model = sm.OLS(y,X).fit()
    rsquared = model.rsquared
    
    # Fit linear regression and calculate alpha and beta
    X = sm.add_constant(x)
    model = regression.linear_model.OLS(y,X).fit()
    alpha = model.params[0]
    beta = model.params[1]

    return beta, alpha, rsquared

results = pd.DataFrame({c: model(df[df[c].notnull()]['MKT Return'], df[df[c].notnull()][c]) for c in cryptos}).transpose()
results.columns = ['beta', 'alpha', 'rsquared']

# change format of each statistic
results['rsquared'] = results['rsquared'].round(decimals=2)
results['alpha'] = results['alpha'].round(decimals=4)
results['beta'] = results['beta'].round(decimals=2)
results['rsquared'] = results['rsquared'].mul(100).astype(int).astype(str).add('%') # change rsquared to percentage form

# rename index of statistics crypto labels
results = results.rename(index={'BTC': 'Bitcoin', 'ETH': 'Ethereum', 'XRP': 'Ripple', 'BCH': 'Bitcoin Cash', 'USDT': 'Tether',
'LTC': 'Litecoin', 'BNB': 'Binance Coin', 'EOS': 'EOS', 'LINK': 'Chainlink', 'XMR': 'Monero', 'BTG': 'Bitcoin Gold', 'ADA': 'Cardano',
'XLM': 'Stellar', 'TRX': 'TRON', 'USDC': 'USDCoin'})

# print all results
print(results)

while True:
    try:
        crypto = input("Cryptocurrency: ")
        if crypto == "BTC" or crypto == "Bitcoin":
            print(results.iloc[0,:])
        elif crypto == "ETH" or crypto == "Ethereum":
            print(results.iloc[1,:])
        elif crypto == "XRP" or crypto == "Ripple":
            print(results.iloc[2,:])
        elif crypto == "BCH" or crypto == "Bitcoin Cash":
            print(results.iloc[3,:])
        elif crypto == "USDT" or crypto == "Tether":
            print(results.iloc[4,:])
        elif crypto == "LTC" or crypto == "Litecoin":
            print(results.iloc[5,:])
        elif crypto == "BNB" or crypto == "Binance Coin":
            print(results.iloc[6,:])
        elif crypto == "EOS":
            print(results.iloc[7,:])
        elif crypto == "LINK" or crypto == "Chainlink":
            print(results.iloc[8,:])
        elif crypto == "XMR" or crypto == "Monero":
            print(results.iloc[9,:])
        elif crypto == "BTG" or crypto == "Bitcoin Gold":
            print(results.iloc[10,:])
        elif crypto == "ADA" or crypto == "Cardano":
            print(results.iloc[11,:])
        elif crypto == "XLM" or crypto == "Stellar":
            print(results.iloc[12,:])
        elif crypto == "TRX" or crypto == "TRON":
            print(results.iloc[13,:])
        elif crypto == "USDC" or crypto == "USDCoin":
            print(results.iloc[14,:])
        else:
            print("No Available Data")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

How can I create a dataframe or multiple dataframes, where I have the statistics for each cryptocurrency for each year, such as: Bitcoin, Ethereum, Ripple,... - beta, alpha, rsquared for 2015, 2016, 2017,...

Also, is it possible to simplify the `while True:` section? It is intended to be a user input function where you are able to type a variant of the name of the crypto and the code would output the statistics for the corresponding data, while giving again the option to select a different crypto if desired, as shown with `if` and `elif` and the `try`, `except`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap your results section in a function, and call it with a filtered data set. For instance, this will give you just the 2020 data.

```
df_2020 = df.filter(like="2020", axis=0)
```

You could calculate your results based on df_2020 instead of the entire df dataset.  To iterate through them all, maybe you could create a sequence of slices:

```
df_list = [df.filter(like=year, axis=0) for year in ("2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020")]
```

Your while loop can be MUCH simpler. Here's an idea that works fine. Notice you can call `results.loc[crypto]` by name instead of hardcoding in row numbers with `.iloc`.

```
abbrev = {'BTC': 'Bitcoin', 'ETH': 'Ethereum', 'XRP': 'Ripple', 'BCH': 'Bitcoin Cash', 'USDT': 'Tether',
'LTC': 'Litecoin', 'BNB': 'Binance Coin', 'EOS': 'EOS', 'LINK': 'Chainlink', 'XMR': 'Monero', 'BTG': 'Bitcoin Gold', 'ADA': 'Cardano',
'XLM': 'Stellar', 'TRX': 'TRON', 'USDC': 'USDCoin'}

while True:
    crypto = input("Cryptocurrency: ")
    crypto = abbrev.get(crypto, crypto) # if the abbreviation is given, try to get it from the abbrev dict
    if crypto in results.index:
        print(results.loc[crypto])    
    elif crypto in ["quit","stop","exit"]:
        break
    else:
        print("No Available Data")
```

Comment: After creating the `df_list`, now I am able to see the data separated by year for all cryptos, but when I modify `results = pd.DataFrame({c: model(df[df[c].notnull()]['MKT Return'], df[df[c].notnull()][c]) for c in cryptos}).transpose()`, by changing `df` to `df_list` and return the statistics separately for each year I get an error. Is this the incorrect way to make this calculation? Instead of having beta, alpha and rsquared calculated for the entire 6 years.

Comment: Once you filter `df` and get a list of dataframes in `df_list`, you can loop over the list, and do everything else the same, but you'll need need to use the filtered dataframe for the operations, including the one you mention here.  Those references to `df` should probably be whatever the variable name for the looped variable is (e.g. `for df_tmp in df_list:`). Everything is the same as what you originally coded, but you're just working on smaller pieces at a time.